# IA-32 movl instruction causes segfault

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm trying to execute the following sample program from page 109 in the book *Professional Assembly Language*.  I'm compiling it with gcc and running it on a 64-bit Fedora 17 host VM using Vmware Player.  In order to get it to compile I had to add the line `.code32` to the top.

```
.code32
.section .data
output:
  .asciz "The largest value is %d\n"
values:
  .int 105, 235, 61, 315, 134, 221, 53, 145, 117, 5
.section .text
.globl main
main:
  nop
  movl values, %ebx
  movl $1, %edi
loop:
  movl values(, %edi, 4), %eax
  cmp %ebx, %eax
  cmova %eax, %ebx
  inc %edi
  cmp $10, %edi
  jne loop
  pushl %ebx
  pushl $output
  call printf
  addl $8, %esp
  pushl $0
  call exit
```

When I run it I get a segmentation fault.  If I step through it in gdb the segfault seems to be occurring at the instruction `movl values, %ebx`.  Here is the output from gdb:

```
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40052c: file testasm1-32.s, line 10.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/auser/dev/lab2/testasm1-32

Breakpoint 1, main () at testasm1-32.s:10
10        nop
(gdb) stepi
11        movl values, %ebx
(gdb) stepi

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
main () at testasm1-32.s:11
11        movl values, %ebx
```

Why is that particular instruction causing a segfault?

Comment: Instead of `.code32` in your source, try telling gcc `-m32`. I suspect `.code32` may be making your data readonly(?).

Comment: @FrankKotler You should post that as an answer, so the OP can accept it, and this question will not show as unanswered.